# How do I bind an ASP.NET Listbox Control to a SharePoint lookup field?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I am adding an ASP.NET Listbox to a custom list form in SharePoint Designer and trying to post the selected items back to a Lookup field when the form is saved. The reason for this is that the Multiple Select Lookup control is hideous, and the Listbox allows customisation with jQuery etc...

I've added a Data Source Control to the page, linking the Listbox to the same field as the Lookup, so that the Listbox displays legal values.

I've added the following line to the Listbox's attributes but with no luck:

```
    __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff5',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@SD_x0020_KB_x0020_Article')}"
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: **N.B.** I am restricted in that I can't use Visual Studio in this solution, only SharePoint Designer.

Comment: what version of sharepoint? 2007 or 2010

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to be done in 2007 with a SharePoint Data Source. The SPDataSource control creates a dataset that you can then bind to your list control.

Chris O'Brien has a great tutorial regarding SPDataSource and binding to controls.

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2008/07/spdatasource-every-developer-friend.html

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse Brian. I can't seem to find the part where he talks about posting back to the Lookup list. In part one he says he will talk about it in part two, but then he seems to forget. Am I missing something?